# Graph VIsualization in NetworkX. Is this loop under node 10 ok?

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, knowledge-graph

I am making a graph visualization under NetworkX, but then I found a self loop around node 10. Of all the graph visualizations I have seen, I have never come across such a thing.

I dont if this is wrong or right, but Mr Stark, I dont feel good about this. Can somebody help me out?

I tried modifying the dataframe that I used to make this graph, but I cant figure it out yet.

```
import dgl as dgl
import networkx as nx

curr = coun_df['Currencies'].to_numpy()
loca = coun_df['Location'].to_numpy()

g = dgl.graph((loca, curr))
print(g)
nxgraph = g.to_networkx().to_undirected()

pos = nx.spring_layout(nxgraph)
nx.draw(nxgraph, pos, with_labels=True, node_color=[[.7, .7, .7]])
```

And this is how the dataframes (both currencies and location are actual categorical variables one-hot encoded to look like this) look like -

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1350J.png)

[This is the image of the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRWnL.png)

I can see currency 10 being mapped to location 10, but I wonder if self-loops are possible in graphs.

Comment: Can you please include the code that you used to make the graph? Ideally, you should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't see any code yet

Comment: If it's not letting you post the edit, it might be because you're not formatting the code correctly. After pasting in the code, highlight it and click the `{}` button from the toolbar.

Comment: I think it is now added to my question.

Comment: Yes, it's there now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a network with loops in it may validly be called a "graph". As the [wiki page indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Graph), there are multiple conventions followed as to what exactly constitutes a "graph" that can typically be inferred from context.

If you want to do so, then the easiest way to get rid of loops is to get rid of rows where `Currencies` and `Location` entries match in the dataframe from which the data is pulled. For instance,

```
import dgl as dgl
import networkx as nx

noloop_df = coun_df[coun_df['Currencies']!=coun_df['Location']]

curr = noloop_df['Currencies'].to_numpy()
loca = noloop_df['Location'].to_numpy()

g = dgl.graph((loca, curr))
print(g)
nxgraph = g.to_networkx().to_undirected()

pos = nx.spring_layout(nxgraph)
nx.draw(nxgraph, pos, with_labels=True, node_color=[[.7, .7, .7]])
```